# What Google Apps can I disable?

Tags: insufficient-memory, performance, google-apps

I'm using a Kitkat 4.4.4 based phone (Samsung Galaxy S Duos 3)
For the most part I don't use G+ or Maps or most of the Google apps provided.
But I do prefer documents being backed up, so I've refrained from shutting down the google app entirely.

Being a phone of very low ram, it kinda cripples the performance. As far as I understand in Android it's not a good idea to kill apps (so normally I hibernate the stuff I don't use). I prefer having the RAM full with apps I actually use.

I'm not really sure what I should be doing with the Google apps. And I would prefer not voiding my warranty by creating a swap partition (using root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, any system app you can disable can safely be disabled. Core system apps will have the disable button greyed out. You can see this if you open App info for the Settings app itself.

Go ahead and disable all Google apps you don't want.

Comment: My concern is that I don't want to accidentally disable the Google Sync. (Contacts, photos etc). Are you suggesting that Google Sync is an Android Core function? A bit of clarity for this specific feature would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Root your phone. Then install it a custom ROM. Custom ROMs doesn't include Google apps at all. Once installed the custom ROM, I suggest you to install the Nano Google apps on your device. Nano apps only include play store and core services. After all this is all you really need. Other apps can be installed via Play Store if you need them

Comment: I would prefer not to root it.

Comment: I'd like to know how you'll get rid of all that crap then

Comment: Rooting would perhaps be the best method, but in my case it's a completely new phone, and I'd prefer not to void its warranty. I would prefer not to overwrite the OEM OS.